# Using the showUserLocation property of MKMapView

Tags: objective-c, gps, location, mkmapview

I have an app at the moment which shows various pins on a map. I've tried setting `mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;` to show the user's current pos, however this crashed my app ("Program received signal: SIGABRT") with the following error message:

```
Mon Oct 19 12:31:27 unknown Hull Ads[3111] <Error>: *** -[MKUserLocation counter]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10ad60
Mon Oct 19 12:31:27 unknown Hull Ads[3111] <Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[MKUserLocation counter]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10ad60'
Mon Oct 19 12:31:27 unknown Hull Ads[3111] <Error>: Stack: (...)
```

This is a little confusing as I haven't used MKUserLocation, or is that the problem?

The app does make use of CoreLocation for other non-related purposes however the app responds in the same way when CoreLocation isn't being used already.

If anyone could help that would be awesome!

Thanks
- James

Comment: My Temporary fix is adding a new pin and changing it's colour, but surely the Current Location pin should be available to use?

Comment: Thanks for asking this question. It ended up helping me too!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Be sure to include the following in this method:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    if ([annotation class] == MKUserLocation.class) {
        return nil;
    }
    ...
}
```

I do hope you've already fixed this by now ;)

Comment: Hey thanks, I've not been working on this project for a while but I will try it later tonight, thanks!!

Comment: Yes this was the fix, thanks! Hopefully this will help someone else with the same problem in the future!!

Comment: Thank you! I was pulling my hair out trying to figure out why I was seeing [MKUserLocation type]: Invalid Selector Sent ... I couldn't figure out why MKUserLocation was showing up. After reading your answer here, I realized that it's the blue dot! The tutorial I was following didn't have the user location shown on the map, so that was not an issue in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Berend for answering the question and james.ingham for asking it! I've been looking for a fix for this problem for months and this thread fixed it for me!

Checking for the MKUserLocation pin type would be the most logical thing to do. But who remembers to do that when implementing viewForAnnotation method.. Even if you are not going to use MKuserlocation in your app it would be safe practice to always do this check to avoid running into problems in the future.